# C++ Best way to "share screens" over socket

Tags: c++

In my current app I need to share screens ala skype or discord, I'd prefer to not use external libs, but will if I have to.

So far I have been sending the screenshots in down-scaled bitmap form over TCP sockets and repainting the window every few milliseconds, this is of course an effort I knew was doomed from the start, is there any api that could save me?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you can't use external libraries, you're in a bit of a pickle, as there are *definitely* people who have solved this problem more efficiently than a single programmer will be able to. But in short, you don't need to send the whole screen every time; just keep track of what pixels have changed and send that. Also, use UDP, as TCP is just going to slow things down here.

Comment: thank's for UDP advice, ok fine which external libraries would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't implemented it myself, I believe that what's usually done is the screen is broken into 16x16 pixel blocks. You can keep the previous screenshot, take a new one, compare which blocks have changed and send only the 16x16 blocks that have changes in them.

You can further improve performance by having a change threshold. If fewer than x pixels have changed in a block, don't send yet. Or if the cumulative sum of the changes in a block (the difference between corresponding pixels) is below some threshold, don't send that block.

The blocks are also often compressed using a lossy compression scheme that really shrinks down the required size you need to send per block. The image blocks are often also sent in 4:2:2 mode, meaning you store the red and blue channels at half the resolution of the green channel. This is based on how the visual system works, but it explains why things that are pure red or pure blue sometimes get blockiness or fringing around them when screen sharing.